# Usage of return select after insert statement T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have seen some store procedure that return select statement after insert like following. What is the usage?

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [dbo].[TableName]
WHERE
    [PrimaryKey] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Google scope_identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Millie's comment. However, if you are new to SQL Server you might find some words in docs new and may have more questions. Hopefully the explanation below will help.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315(v=sql.105).aspx says:

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

In your stored procedure, the `INSERT` statement is done on a table with an identity column. This identity column gets an incremented auto-number during the insertion process. To know what this number is, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function is used.

For example:

```
create table employees (id int identity(1,1) primary key, fullname varchar(100));
insert into employees (fullname) values ('John Smith');
select scope_identity(); -- will return the ID of the inserted record
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41f84/2 (keep on pressing Run SQL to see the last entered data's ID).

You can then use this auto generated ID to do some more work, such as write to an audit table, or write more data to a details table etc.

Comment: In the `select` statement in your question, `scope_identity()` is perhaps the most reliable way to get information about last inserted record. It is not compulsory. You could use `select top 1 * ... order by id desc` if you are sure no other insert has happened during your transaction.